# Using Facebook access token claim with Aspnet Identity in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm using Aspnet Identity in MVC5. Facebook is an external login. I need to store Facebook access token for later use. I have read several topic about it but i still have some issues:
I setup by this way:

1. When configure authentication for Facebook, i have added claim for Facebook access token:

   `OnAuthenticated = async context =>
               {
                   context.Identity.AddClaim(new     System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                   ...
               }`
2. When external login done, it bring claim with Facebook token:

   `public async Task ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
   {
       var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
       //The loginInfo object contains the claim i needed (the facebook token)
       var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
           switch (result)
           {
               case SignInStatus.Success:
               //find user and save the claim to database.
               var u = UserManager.Find(loginInfo.Login);
               await SaveAccessToken(u, loginInfo.ExternalIdentity);
               return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
               break;
               .......
           }
   }`
3. The SaveAccessToken method is just call the UserManager.AddClaimAsync to save claim that contains Facebook access token to database:

   `private async Task SaveAccessToken(ApplicationUser user, ClaimsIdentity identity)
   {
           var userclaims = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id);
           foreach (var at in (from claims in identity.Claims
               where claims.Type.Equals("FacebookAccessToken")
               select new Claim(claims.Type, claims.Value, claims.ValueType, claims.Issuer)).Where(at => !userclaims.Contains((Claim) at)))
           {
               await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, at);
           }
   }`

The token is successfully saved to AspnetUserClaims table of database. However, after login done, the site redirect to other action, the User object has the identity of type "ApplicationCookie" and there isn't any claim named: "FacebookAccessToken". Several topics said that i have to add custom claim when identity object is created by overriding CreateIdentityAsync method of UserManager class. like that:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public async override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser applicationUser, string authenticationType)
    {
        var identity = await base.CreateIdentityAsync(applicationUser, authenticationType);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("mycustomclaim", applicationUser.Avatar));
        return identity;
    }
}
```

However, as i noticed, the identity is created when ExternalSignInAsync executed. So inside method CreateIdentityAsync, how can i get a claim value of loginInfo object which is passed from ExternalSignInAsync. If i cannot, is there any way, i can add custom claim to current identity after ExternalSignInAsync successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32062245/976004) and i can add claim immediately after login success:

`SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FacebookAccessToken", loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type.Equals("FacebookAccessToken")).Value));`

But not sure this code has issues in some cases.